# Parameter not passing in Swift api call

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, urlsession

We were passing email and password but it does not sent in API call,

Code

```
    Button(action: { Task{ func apiCall() { 
    let endpoint = "https://new.demozab.com/cryptoco/mobileapi/public/api/login" 
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { return } 
    var request = URLRequest(url: url) request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") 
    request.httpMethod = "POST" 
    let parameters: [String: Any Hashable] = [ "email":Email, "password":Password, "device_id" : "abcdef", "device_type" : "ios", "ip" : "0.0.0.0" ] 
    do { request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .fragmentsAllowed) } 
    catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) return } let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data , _ , error ) in guard let data = data ,error == nil else{ return } 
    do{ let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: .fragmentsAllowed) print("Success \(response)") } 
    catch{ print(error) } } 
    task.resume() } 
    apiCall() } },
```

Output:

```
Success {
    message = "The email field is required.";
    response = "";
    status = 0;
}
```

[image: Apicall Postman Success Response]

Comment: Could the code be not in one line? It's hard to read it.

Comment: You can ask POSTMAN to generate Swift code and see what could be the difference between yours and that one. And ` .fragmentsAllowed` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `apiCall()` function works and correctly passes parameters in the body for the `URLRequest`.

Most likely you need to recheck the documentation for the endpoint. I hit the URL with the same parameters you provided (In Postman, with a test email and test password), and I received the same error response from the server.

Comment: API call working fine with params in Postman. But params not passing in api call with swift.